# TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I have a huge text file (1 GB), where each "line" is accordong to the syntax:

```
[number] [number]_[number]
```

For example:

```
123 123_1234
45 456_45    12 12_12
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
  line 46, in open_delimited
    pieces = re.findall(r"(\d+)\s+(\d+_\d+)", remainder + chunk, re.IGNORECASE)
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple
```

on this code:

```
def open_delimited(filename, args):
    with open(filename, args, encoding="UTF-16") as infile:
        chunksize = 10000
        remainder = ''
        for chunk in iter(lambda: infile.read(chunksize), ''):
            pieces = re.findall(r"(\d+)\s+(\d+_\d+)", remainder + chunk, re.IGNORECASE)
            for piece in pieces[:-1]:
                yield piece
            remainder = pieces[-1]
        if remainder:
            yield remainder

filename = 'data/AllData_2000001_3000000.txt'
for chunk in open_delimited(filename, 'r'): 
    print(chunk)
```

Comment: Remainder is a tuple in the second iteration in the loop rather than a string

Comment: Your code fails as well if `chunk` is a partial record. In this case, you have no match. Better add it to `remainder`, split and then try to split it where appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`re.findall()` returns a sequence of *tuples* when more than one capturing group is given in the pattern. Your pattern has two such groups. Thus, each `piece` consists of `(number, number_number)` pairs:

```
>>> re.findall(r"(\d+)\s+(\d+_\d+)", '45 456_45    12 12_12')
[('45', '456_45'), ('12', '12_12')]
```

Note that since you are matching whitespace and digits *only*, the `re.IGNORECASE` flag is entirely redundant.

You assign the last such `piece` to `remainder`, then loop back up and prepend that to `chunk`, and that doesn't work:

```
>>> ('12', '12_12') + '123 123_1234\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple
```

Perhaps you wanted to rejoin the values into a valid piece of text again:

```
remainder = '{} {} '.format(*pieces[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

As already said, you have a bug in your processing: `findall()` gives a list of tuples.

An alterative approach could be

```
def open_delimited(filename, args):
    with open(filename, args, encoding="UTF-16") as infile:
        chunksize = 10000
        remainder = ''
        for chunk in iter(lambda: infile.read(chunksize), ''):
            remainder += chunk # add it to the to-be-processed string
            pieces = list(re.finditer(r"(\d+)\s+(\d+_\d+)", remainder, re.IGNORECASE))
            # Those pieces are match objects.
            for piece in pieces[:-1]: # omit the last one, as before
                yield piece.group() # the whole match
            remainder = remainder[pieces[-1].start()] # the last one tells us where to start again.
        if remainder:
            yield remainder
```

Here, the `pieces` are not tuples of strings, but they are match objects. They don't tell us just what they contain, but as well where they come from.

This allows for easy "re-creating" of the "remainder".